# Unable to ping guest from host and vise versa in Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: linux, virtualbox, scientific-linux

This is my Oracle Virtual Box Version 4.2.18 r88780

Details of my host machine

Operating System : Scientific Linux 6.4

**I am using static ip**

```
root@localhost ~]# ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1E:EC:95:18:66  
          inet addr:192.168.1.4  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Interrupt:19
```

Details of my guest machine

Operating System: CentOS 6.4

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:6D:C3:A6  
          inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe6d:c3a6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:360 (360.0 b)  TX bytes:1746 (1.7 KiB)
```

This is my Virtual Box Network Setting

[image]

This is the ping output

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.1.4 
PING 192.168.1.4 (192.168.1.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.6 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.6 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.6 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.1.4 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 5640ms
pipe 3
```

I tried flushing iptables also still not working, loopback is working.

Comment: Do you have a static IP on the guest?

Comment: Yes in guest also i am using static IP

Comment: In the past I have had troubles configuring static IP in VBox guests with bridges. Can you try, just once, not to set the static IP, and see whether this works? This will also avoid the need for setting up a proper route inside the guest OS; you had done that, had you not?

Comment: i tried that also not working

Comment: can you show your routing table?

Comment: Sorry Sorry discard my last reply,  I am using internet by using USB tethering, so in host machine Interface is usb0 and problem is that in guest machine usb0 interface is not showing,  in virtual machine network setting i change the interface to usb0 but still in guest machine interface is not showing, so i dont no what to do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10858/discussion-between-max-and-mariusmatutiae)

Comment: If your host connects via an interface called usb0, then before starting your VM select networking, do NOT select bridge adapter, choose instead NAT, then choose usb0 as the interface to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the easiest setup is to use NAT and define port forwarding as needed.

For example, a simple Port Forwarding setup  allowing connection to the VM from the host through shh on `localhost:10022`, and to the webserver on `localhost:8080`would be:

(Name - Protocol - Host IP : Host Port - Guest IP : Guest Port) 
SSH - TCP - 127.0.0.1 : 10022 - 10.0.2.15(*) : 22 
www - TCP - 127.0.0.1 : 8080 - 10.0.2.15(*) : 80

(*) virtual IP returned by a `ifconfig` from the VM, most probably different for you.

Should you have special requirements preventing NAT from working, please give some details about what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to create a network between host and guest,  I want to practice ftp,  http,  and samba servers and some file transfer protocals also but i am unable to configure connection only .